# Is it possible to serve Progressive-JPEG images as different quality for various devices?

Tags: image, jpeg

Say there's a large size Progressive jpeg.

For example, For desktop serve the image as 100% quality
and for tablet serve the image as 70% quality
and for mobile serve the image as 40% quality.

One source image for multiple devices. Is it possible?
If not, there's a lot to do in server-side.

When "abc.jpg" is uploaded, it must be resized to each "abc-700w.jpg", "abc-400w.jpg" ....

I hope the JPEG has this spec, but google result seems nothing..

Comment: There is no concept of "quality" as a percentage in JPEG so it is not clear what you are trying to do. Image quality in JPEG is a function of several parameters.

Comment: @user334400 As P-JPEG is repeatly loaded and got better quality, for example for pc : full load the image and for tablet, mobile : stop load in the middle. I don't know this is my rough scenario.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Maybe you save some processing time. It does not save memory.

Comment: @user3344003 I have to make many images like "abc-700w.jpg", "abc-400w.jpg"  ... on the server side. But by using P-JPEG's feature, I think maybe it can responsively be served to various devices. This is for mobile users, mobile data usages and performance(load time) issuses etc.

Comment: The image size is the same in progressive and sequential JPEG.

Comment: I know the each filesize is almost same. 
I mean, for now, I have to create multiple files for multiple devices. 
I'm asking like one source multi use, one image multi use(for various device) is possible? 
If it is possible we don't have to create multiple files. 
when the webserver stop responding the image(P-JPEG) in the middle, the users receives the more lightweight and low-quality image. 
(because they don't need to get the original image!) 
It may be done by combination of webserver(apache) and client header whatever.
It is just my imagination. My apology for my horrible English

Comment: The image size is the same in pixels as well.

Comment: That said you can stop the processing of progressive JPEG in the middle and leave a lower quality image. That does not save you anything.